# How do I remove items from cart using splice in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm making an application using Vue.js I need to remove items when they are added to the cart and have those items be available on the products page again once they are removed from the cart. Below is the code for the `html` file and the `js` file that includes the array `subjects`:

The code mainly works fine, except when I add, for example, all five of the same product and go to the checkout page to remove them, it takes three clicks to remove all products when it should be taking five. This problem is not present when I add and remove just one or two products.

The issue, I believe, could be present in the methods `findModule` and `remove`. However, I can't seem to understand what is causing this issue. Sorry for the uncommented code. Ask me if you have any questions.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// lessons.js

let subjects = [{"id":1,"title":"Mathematics","location":"Dubai","price":"40","image":"../images/mathematics.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":2,"title":"History","location":"Dubai","price":"50","image":"../images/history.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":3,"title":"Physics","location":"Sharjah","price":"30","image":"../images/physics.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":4,"title":"Information Technology","location":"Ras Al-Khaima","price":"55","image":"../images/it.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":5,"title":"Biology","location":"Dubai","price":"45","image":"../images/biology.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":6,"title":"Chemistry","location":"Al Ain","price":"35","image":"../images/chemistry.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":7,"title":"English Language","location":"Dubai","price":"60","image":"../images/english.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":8,"title":"Geography","location":"Abu Dhabi","price":"25","image":"../images/geography.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":9,"title":"Drama","location":"Sharjah","price":"40","image":"../images/drama.jpeg","spaces":5},{"id":10,"title":"Art","location":"Dubai","price":"35","image":"../images/art.webp","spaces":5}];


// page script

let webstore = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sitename: 'After School Lessons',
    showSubject: true,
    subject: subjects,
    cart: [],
    sort: "",
    search: "",
    subjectOrder: "",
    order: {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      phone: ""
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addItem(subject) {
      this.cart.push(subject);
      subject.spaces--;
    },
    showCheckout() {
      this.showSubject = this.showSubject ? false : true
    },
    submitForm() {
      alert("Order Submitted!")
    },
    canAddToCart(subject) {
      return subject.spaces > this.cartCount(subject.id);
    },
    cartCount(id) {
      let count = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
        if (this.cart[i] === id) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      return count;
    },

    findModule(id) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.subject.length; i++) {
        if (this.subject[i].id === id) {
          return this.subject[i];
        }
      }
    },
    remove(id) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.cart.length; i++) {
        if (this.cart[i].id === id) {
          this.cart.splice(i, 1);
          this.findModule(id).spaces += 1;
        }
      }
      if (this.cart.length === 0) {
        this.showSubject = true
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    cartItemCount: function() {
      return this.cart.length || ''
    },
    sortedSubjects() {

      let subjectArray = this.subject;
      if (this.search != "" && this.search) {
        let subjectArray = this.subject;
        subjectArray = subjectArray.filter((object) => {
          return (
            object.title.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())
          );
        });
        return subjectArray;
      }

      if (this.sort == "price") {
        if (this.subjectOrder == "ascending") {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.price > b.price ? 1 : -1);
        } else {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.price < b.price ? 1 : -1);
        }
      } else if (this.sort == "location") {
        if (this.subjectOrder == "ascending") {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.location > b.location ? 1 : -1);
        } else {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.location < b.location ? 1 : -1);
        }
      } else if (this.sort == "title") {
        if (this.subjectOrder == "ascending") {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1);
        } else {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.title < b.title ? 1 : -1);
        }
      } else if (this.sort == "spaces") {
        if (this.subjectOrder == "ascending") {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.spaces > b.spaces ? 1 : -1);
        } else {
          return subjectArray.sort((a, b) => a.spaces < b.spaces ? 1 : -1);
        }
      } else {
        return subjectArray;
      }

    }

  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1 v-text="sitename" style="font-family:Trebuchet MS;"></h1>
  <input id="search" type="search" v-model="search" placeholder="Search">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button @click="showCheckout" :disabled="!cartItemCount > 0">
            <span class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></span>
            {{cartItemCount}}
            Checkout
        </button>
  <br>

  <div v-if="showSubject">
    <br>
    <h3>Sort by:</h3>
    <input type="radio" value="ascending" v-model="subjectOrder" id="ascending">
    <label for="ascending">Ascending</label>
    <input type="radio" value="descending" v-model="subjectOrder" id="descending">
    <label for="descending">Descending</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" value="price" v-model="sort" id="price">
    <label for="price">Price</label>
    <input type="radio" value="location" v-model="sort" id="location">
    <label for="price">Location</label>
    <input type="radio" value="title" v-model="sort" id="title">
    <label for="title">Subject</label>
    <input type="radio" value="spaces" v-model="sort" id="spaces">
    <label for="spaces">Availability</label>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div v-for="subject in sortedSubjects">
      <br>
      <img width="450" height="350" v-bind:src="subject.image">
      <h2 v-text="subject.title"></h2>
      <p>Location: {{subject.location}}</p>
      <p>Price: AED {{subject.price}}</p>
      <p>Available Spaces: {{subject.spaces}}</p>
      <button v-on:click="addItem(subject)" :disabled="!canAddToCart(subject)">
                    Add to Cart
                    <span class="fa-solid fa-square-plus"></span>
                </button>

      <span v-if="subject.spaces === cartCount(subject.id)">
                    Out of Stock
                </span>
      <span v-else-if="subject.spaces - cartCount(subject.id) < 3">
                    Only {{subject.spaces - cartCount(subject.id)}} left!
                </span>
      <span v-else>Buy Now!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <h2>Checkout</h2>
    <div v-for="subject in cart">
      <img width="450" height="350" v-bind:src="subject.image">
      <h2>{{subject.title}}</h2>
      <p>Location: {{subject.location}}</p>
      <p>Price: AED {{subject.price}}</p>
      <p>Spaces: {{subject.spaces}}</p>
      <button @click="remove(subject.id)">Remove from Cart</button>
    </div>
    <p>
      <strong>First Name: </strong>
      <input v-model.trim="order.firstname">
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Last Name: </strong>
      <input v-model.trim="order.lastname">
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Phone Number: </strong>
      <input v-model="order.phone">
    </p>

    <h2>Order Information</h2>
    <p>First Name: {{order.firstname}}</p>
    <p>Last Name: {{order.lastname}}</p>
    <p>Phone Number: {{order.phone}}</p>

    <button @click="submitForm" :disabled="!(/^(?!\s*$)[a-zA-Z.+\s'-]+$/.test(this.order.firstname) && /^(?!\s*$)[a-zA-Z.+\s'-]+$/.test(this.order.lastname) && /^(?!\s*$)[0-9.+\s'-]+$/.test(this.order.phone) && this.order.phone.length === 10)">
            Place Order</button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.8/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well it's seems to be an array, so simply remove it from the array, you can use `.splice()` for example : `this.cart.splice(5)` to remove the product at index 5. Avoid using .slice() and replacing the whole array.

Comment: Yeah I am using splice.. but it doesn't work properly if there are 5 of the same product in the cart. So I am pretty sure the change is required in the methods that I mentioned, but still not sure what I could change.

Comment: Then you need to find all instances of that product and remove them all, and also you need to be careful because you are removing items from the array so indexes are shifting. I think you should use the `.filter()` function, it will remove the items you don't want without having to care about indexes shifting.

Comment: In your remove method, you should iterate from end, not from beginning.